# Slow fadeIn on page with video - Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5-video, fadein

I have a to slow fadeIn effect when I tring to show simple popup by clicking on button. Without video all of it works fine.
Video on my page have a 100% size and fixed position

```
video#bgvid{
    position: fixed; right: 0; bottom: 0;
    min-width: 100%; min-height: 100%;
    width: auto; height: auto; z-index: -100;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Also, there is a popup html code

```
<div class="blackpopup">
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</div>
```

And css:

```
.blackpopup{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.58);
}
```

Javascript code is simple:

```
var popUpThank = jQuery(".blackpopup");
    var submitButton = jQuery("#submit");

    submitButton.click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        popUpThank.fadeIn();
    });
```

So, how to make it not so slow and where is the problem?

Comment: so where is the question?

Comment: I'm sorry, I updated my question

Comment: Looks fine here on Firefox, video is playing but when you click register popup fades in normally.

Comment: @artm - Okay, but what about webkit browsers?

Comment: @twister0k When I look at it at chrome popup displays normally as well but it's displayed at the top of the page, not where you click register, you need to scroll up to see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: not saturating the browser's memory with a hell of a heavy video.
Try doing the same removing the video tag it will work.
Compress it better, or with low quality as it's a background object.
I can point you to sorenson squeeze app for that.